# Cannot update symfony/security from 4.4.1 to 5.0.1

Tags: symfony, composer-php, upgrade

I have my symfony app in version 4.4.1 and I want to upgrade it to version 5.0.1.
When I delete my *composer.lock* and execute `composer update` it throws error as if there is no even version 5 released...

result

```
 - The requested package symfony/security 5.0.* exists as symfony/security[2.0.4, 2.0.5, ..., v4.4.0-BETA2, v4.4.0-RC1, v4.4.1] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

I assume that my "*constraint*" is this line from composer.json: `"symfony/security": "5.0.*",`.

Here is the prove that I have symfony version equal 4.4.1 (`composer outdated`):

```
symfony/cache                      v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Cache component with PSR-6, PSR-16, and tags
symfony/config                     v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Config Component
symfony/console                    v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Console Component
symfony/debug-bundle               v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony DebugBundle
symfony/dependency-injection       v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony DependencyInjection Component
symfony/doctrine-bridge            v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Doctrine Bridge
symfony/dotenv                     v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Registers environment variables from a .env file
symfony/error-handler              v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony ErrorHandler Component
symfony/event-dispatcher           v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts v1.1.7 v2.0.1 Generic abstractions related to dispatching event
symfony/expression-language        v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony ExpressionLanguage Component
symfony/filesystem                 v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Filesystem Component
symfony/finder                     v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Finder Component
symfony/framework-bundle           v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony FrameworkBundle
symfony/http-foundation            v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel                v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/inflector                  v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Inflector Component
symfony/mime                       v4.4.1 v5.0.1 A library to manipulate MIME messages
symfony/property-access            v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony PropertyAccess Component
symfony/routing                    v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Routing Component
symfony/security-bundle            v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony SecurityBundle
symfony/translation                v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Translation Component
symfony/twig-bridge                v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Twig Bridge
symfony/twig-bundle                v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony TwigBundle
symfony/validator                  v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Validator Component
symfony/var-dumper                 v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony mechanism for exploring and dumping PHP variables
symfony/var-exporter               v4.4.1 v5.0.1 A blend of var_export() + serialize() to turn any serializable dat...
symfony/web-profiler-bundle        v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony WebProfilerBundle
symfony/yaml                       v4.4.1 v5.0.1 Symfony Yaml Component
```

Here is the prove that I have symfony/security equal 4.4.1 (`composer show`)

```
symfony/security                       v4.4.1  Symfony Security Component
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: symfony/security no longer exists, its 4 separate packages now. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security.html

Comment: I removed "symfony/security": "5.0.*" from composer.json and executed `composer update` with error about `\config\routes\dev\twig.yaml` file. I just overwrited twig.yaml with framework.yaml from new symfony 5.0.1 project... I had to also execute `composer require symfony/error-handler` and change `Debug` class namespace in index.php in my public folder... Well that wasn't easy as documentation said. Also downvoting this question is not necessary... I didn't want to read whole doc once again to just upgrade to 5.0 which I read that it's mainly bug fiexes version.

Comment: Yeah there is a few things required to upgrade. By the way it wasn't me that downvoted you!

Comment: If it was much more unsupported components I would definitely consider creating a new project and migrate whole /src and /assets folders and much more just to avoid endless checking which component to remove and which to add of course manually because composer has some problems with it as I said above.

Answer (score 1):

`symfony/security` 4 split into multiple packages in Symfony 5.

You need to replace them in `composer.json`, e.g.:

```
-"symfony/security": "^4.4",
+"symfony/security-core": "^5.0",
+"symfony/security-http": "^5.0",
+"symfony/security-csrf": "^5.0",
+"symfony/security-guard": "^5.0",
```

But looking at comments under the question, there were more BC changes you need to fix.

**I wrote about in [full upgrade post - How we Upgraded Pehapkari.cz from Symfony 4 to 5 in 25 days](https://pehapkari.cz/blog/2019/12/23/how-we-upgraded-pehapkari-cz-from-symfony-4-to-5-in-25-days).** I think you'll find it useful.